# How to insert HTML code in IF-Else statement in xHtml?

Tags: java, jsf, if-statement, primefaces

I have **primefaces** datatable on my page.

And I displaying two number on my column.

I did like this :

```
 #{pushNotification.status==1? 'FINISHED' : 'STOP'}
 *// If the data == 1 show 'FINISHED' else show 'STOP'*
```

But I want to run HTML code in if statement, not just text.

I've tried like this ;

```
 #{pushNotification.status==1? '<a>FINISHED</a>' : 'STOP'}
```

gaves me "**EL Expression**" error;

```
javax.el.ELException: EL Expression Unbalanced: ... #{pushNotification.status==1? '' : 'STOP' '
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText.findVarLength(ELText.java:428)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText.parse(ELText.java:373)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText.parse(ELText.java:325)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextUnit.flushTextBuffer(TextUnit.java:139)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextUnit.addInstruction(TextUnit.java:127)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextUnit.startTag(TextUnit.java:197)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CompilationManager.pushTag(CompilationManager.java:313)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler$CompilationHandler.startElement(SAXCompiler.java:247)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
```

Comment: It is not about problem your el expression.Can you try this :  #{pushNotification.status=='1' ? 'FINISHED' : 'STOP'}

Comment: I know its working. But I want to run html code in if or else statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{pushNotification.status == 1}">FINISHED</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{pushNotification.status != 1}">STOP</ui:fragment>
```

Also add **xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"** in html tag